# Apache - redirect all traffic to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect all traffic to /something using VirtualHost.

For instance:

```
/ => /something
/foo => /something
/blog/foo => /something
/something/blog/post => /something/blog/post
```

I've tried this but I think it's still looking:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/something
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /something/$1 [NC,L]
```